# Building Maven project with company internal repositories

Tags: java, maven, maven-3

I maintain project at my company which uses legacy dependencies. Most of them are in provided scope, because they are present on my JBoss classpath. I need them only for compilation.

I have also declared in my pom.xml two additional repositories - Jboss Releases and Jboss Thirdparty Releases. Despite the fact, I do not declare explicitly OSS Sonatype Repository some dependencies are also downloaded from there. It confuses me a lot.

Now, I have to change this project to use with my company internal Nexus repositories, but some transitive dependencies are missing.

**What in your opinion would be the easiest way to fill with jars my internal Nexus and to change my project to use only company internal  repos?**

Two approaches comes to my mind:
1. Create empty local repository, and then import it into Nexus.
2. Retrieve from build log what repositories are downloaded and then to create mirror of all that places.

Comment: If you see deps being downloaded from `OSS Sonatype Repository` it is either because you have a parent `pom.xml` containing that repo, a `settings.xml` containing that repo, or a dependency or tranzitive dependency referencing that repo (dependencies can reference custom repositories in their own `pom.xml`).

Comment: I am aware of that, but how to migrate project to use only my company internal repository. What would be the best technique.

Comment: `<mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>ARIS_Allowed_Repos</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>repo url</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>` you use these tags in your setting.xml

Comment: OK, but how this help me with moving proper artifacts into my internal repository? As I understand this is only an option when internal mirror is already prepared and filled with jars.

Comment: @Michał Mielec If I knew the answer I'd have made an Answer instead of a Comment. I just figured I'd chip in here with my 2 cents (i.e. I answered only a small part of the question).
And if you knew that, then you shouldn't have written this in your question: "Despite the fact, I do not declare explicitly OSS Sonatype Repository some dependencies are also downloaded from there. It confuses me a lot."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your internal repository manager, you can add [proxy repositories](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/confignx-sect-manage-repo.html) and point your `pom.xml` to use only your internal repository.